# Remove vertical stripes in opencv with C ++

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, stripes

[image: Sample Image]

I am a beginner. I would like to use the library functions of OpenCV.

Comment: The first thing I notice is some of the coffee beans in the second image are _not_ in the same position or orientation as the first. That seems like a very unusual artifact of image processing. That aside, try breaking your problem down into smaller problems. A very naive first pass would be to detect the relative brightness of each column, and then make an overall adjustment to the image that normalizes brightness to the average. Subsequent filtering may be required to clean up artifacts from this, but that would be a very good start.

Comment: @paddy Yeah - find the difference. :-)

Comment: @paddy obviously it's not about the objects but about the defective/uncorrected image sensor.

Comment: learn about flatfield and darkfield correction. this is what you need here. the sensor needs to be calibrated. fixing this up after the fact with bandpass/lowpass filtering is inferior to calibrating the sensor.

Answer (score 5):

One traditional way of removing stripes is to apply a mask to the offending frequencies in the frequency domain.

Something like this:
Input image -> dft -> apply mask -> idft -> Output image

[image]

There is an article in the opencv documentation about this type of analysis:

https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d8/d01/tutorial_discrete_fourier_transform.html

Unfortunately I don't have a C/C++ example available, but it shouldn't be much different as the opencv library provides functions for dft and idft.

Example of the application of the mask in frequency domain in Python

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

img_input = cv2.imread('beans.png', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

img = img_input.copy()

f = np.fft.fft2(img)

fshift = np.fft.fftshift(f)

h, w = fshift.shape

spectrum_input = 20*np.log(np.abs(fshift))

for j in range(w//2 - 4):
    fshift[h//2][j] = 0.0
    
for j in range(w//2 + 5,w):
    fshift[h//2][j] = 0.0

f = np.fft.ifftshift(fshift)

img = np.fft.ifft2(f)

img = np.abs(img)
img = img.astype(np.uint8)

spectrum = 20*np.log(np.abs(fshift))

fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 2)

axs[0,0].imshow(img_input, cmap = 'gray')
axs[0,1].imshow(spectrum_input, cmap = 'gray')
axs[1,0].imshow(img, cmap = 'gray')
axs[1,1].imshow(spectrum, cmap = 'gray')

plt.show()
```

Comment: can you share the code you get these results with ?

Comment: I usually do image processing with Python nowadays, so i don't have code for C/C++ (as the question is asking). I just generated the image to illustrate the idea behind. It shouldn't be much different in C/C++ as the opencv library provides functions for dft and idft. I don't think the code in Python would be adequate in the answer to the question, since he is asking specifically for C++.

Comment: it would be better to share even in python code you generated this. It would be a reference for the people meeting same issue. It can be convertable to c++ if needed

Comment: Here it is, thanks for the orientation. Sometimes I try to be extra careful when shifting from the question, as it is usually not well received.

Comment: This is not a good method. It removes high frequency information from the image, and doesn’t remove low frequency components of the stripes. This processing is typically applied when a signal of a specific frequency is overlaid on the image. That is not the case here.

Comment: Why would you loop over `i` but then only do something when `i == (h//2)`?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I fixed the loop. What technique would you suggest for correction? I know there are alternatives, but frequency masking always seems to provide good enough results for me when I have to deal with these kind of interference, and is simple enough for a beginner to understand.